# In Angular, how to stopPropagation() of TR click event when checkbox has change event?

Tags: angular, event-handling, click

I'm using Angular 6.  I have a table row (`<TR>`) with a click event.  For testing purposes let's just say the event prints "quack!" to the console.  This is the HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of things" (click)="quack()">
  ...
</tr>
```

In the component:

```
quack() {
  console.log('quack!');
}
```

Now, within this row I have a checkbox.  It's a Bootstrap 4 custom checkbox but I don't think that's material to the problem I need to solve.  That checkbox has a custom directive which adds a **change** event handler (not a **click** event).  A simplified version of the HTML is:

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of things" (click)="quack()">
  ...
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cb{{t.id}}" name="cb{{t.id}}" 
     [my-directive]="b.somedata">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="cb{{t.id}}">&nbsp;</label>
  </div>
  ...
</tr>
```

In the my-directive directive code:

```
@HostListener('change') onChange() {
  // do some stuff...
}
```

## The problem

What I *want* to happen is for the `quack()` function to fire when anyone clicks on the row, *unless* they click the checkbox.  When they check or uncheck the checkbox, I want the `onChange()` function in the custom-directive to fire, and I want no quacking.

The "quack!" appears in the console once each time I click on the row, which is correct.  What's odd is that when I click on the checkbox I get *two* quacks and then the `onChange()` handler fires.  I'd like zero quacks, I expected one, but I got two!

- Incidentally, when I check/uncheck the checkbox by hitting the spacebar instead of clicking, I still get one quack. I can't imagine where the click event comes from.

I added `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();"` to the `<input>` element, thinking this would solve the problem.  It brings me down to just one quack when I click on the checkbox.  I'd like to get to zero.  **How can I prevent the click on the checkbox from propagating a `click()` event that triggers a `quack()`?**

- By the way, after adding that snippet, toggling the checkbox with spacebar produces zero quacks.

Comment: I did not read everything but when Angular calls its custom `(click)` event, the browser event is already propagated so you can not stop it. Though you can still stop a click event by creating your own click event with plain javascript.

Comment: @Ploppy - Are you sure about that? I think that you can stop the propagation in the `(click)` event handler.

Comment: You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aheu8b). It appears to work if we handle the `click` event in the directive and stop its propagation. Note: In my code example, I made sure that the `id` and the `name` of each check box is unique (but the click management worked without that change).

Comment: Did you try event.preventDefault() or return false from the event to prevent the default behavior of the browser.

Comment: In [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yncjq9), I stop the propagation in the `(click)` event handler of the check box.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I altered the sample code to show a unique id/name for each checkbox, as you suggest.  My problem turns out to be due to the Bootstrap 4 custom checkbox; your solutions work great for any normal checkbox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The Answer

I was wrong to assume that it being a Bootstrap 4 custom checkbox was immaterial -- in fact that was the key to my problem.  In this usage of Bootstrap 4, the `<input>` itself is invisible!  The thing you see on screen that looks like a checkbox is actually generated by CSS.  So the `click` event wouldn't belong to that `<input>` element in the first place.

To solve the problem, I moved `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();"` to the `<div>` element that wraps the custom checkbox, like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of things" (click)="quack()">
  ...
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="cb{{t.id}}" name="cb1" 
     [my-directive]="b.somedata">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="cb{{t.id}}">&nbsp;</label>
  </div>
  ...
</tr>
```

If I were using normal checkboxes instead of these Bootstrap 4 custom ones, either of the solutions mentioned by ConnorsFan would have worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the `stopPropagation()` friend!

Comment: I had the same problem with `custom-checkbox` and as workaround i used simple checkbox. Your answer makes that, i can use `custom-checkbox` again. Thank You! :)