# with Angular how to stopPropagation() of checkbox click event inside a table row?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an angular material table with a row showing customers and another child table showing their orders. On clicking anywhere in the row it expands the row for showing the customers orders. When I click in the checkbox in the customer row I don't want the orders child table to open. I have tried a couple of things but with no luck. Can someone recommend what would work with this scenario. Your helps really appreciated, thanks!

I have tried putting `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();` on the checkbox, on the  container as well and that didnt work. I also tried to make a directive as shown in [In Angular, how to stopPropagation() of TR click event when checkbox has change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884820/in-angular-how-to-stoppropagation-of-tr-click-event-when-checkbox-has-change)
but this still does not stop the `(click)="expandCollapse(row)` on the `<tr>` from firing.

Checkbox code:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="column.key == 'all' && column.key !== 'sort'">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.width.px]="75">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation();
      (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
      [checked]="hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
      [indeterminate]="hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
    >
    </mat-checkbox>
    <span class="checkbox-text"></span>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox
      (change)="$event ? toggle(row.customerId) : null"
      [checked]="isSelected(row.customerId)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Parent material row:

```
<tr mat-row
  [ngClass]="{'highlighted': isSelected(row.customerId) }"
  *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnKeys;" class="example-element-row"
  [class.example-expanded-row]="isSelected(row.customerId)"
  (click)="expandCollapse(row)" id="rowcustomer-{{row.rowIdex}}">
</tr>
```

Comment: the `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();` works for me, can you provide a stackblitz. you can try it using [Angular material sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/moyvxkneovqn?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts) just change the row click event.

Comment: Did you try `$event.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the documentation sample of Angular Material ([Angular Material)](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

by default you would have something like below in your component.html file:

```
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
    (click)="selection.toggle(row)"
 </tr>
```

you remove the click event
so it would look like below:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
 </tr>
```

and it should work